# Is it possible to us .ascx in PHP natively?

Tags: c#, php, ascx

I have a webserver that runs asp.net and php. I have various .ascx controls that I need to use on the php side. Is there a way to use these controls in php natively? Or do I need to rewrite them in php?

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot run ASP.NET code*. You will need to rewrite your controls in PHP.

*: At least, not in any sensible, performant way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use them direclty on a php page but if you encapsulate them on one or more aspx pages, it could work.